# Splitting large XML files into manageble sections for Hadoop

Tags: xml, hadoop

Is there a input class to deal with [multiple] large XML files based on their tree structure in Hadoop? I have a set of XML files that are of the same schema, but I need to split them into sections of data, as opposed to breaking the sections up.

For example the XML file would be:

```
<root>
  <parent> data </parent>
  <parent> more data</parent>
  <parent> even more data</parent>
</root>
```

I would define each section as:
/root/parent.

What I'm asking is: Is there a record input reader already included for Hadoop to do this?

Comment: How important is the performance? record input reader would be ok, but very slow... would that be acceptable?

Comment: eh.. its a school assignment so performance is not a big deal ... but it would be preferable

Comment: Shouldn't that be listed as an answer instead of comment?

Comment: wasn't sure it answers your question or not :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the [Cloud9 project at UMD](http://www.umiacs.umd.edu/~jimmylin/cloud9/docs/index.html) might help you with this.

The library provides has an [XMLInputFormat class](http://www.umiacs.umd.edu/~jimmylin/cloud9/docs/api/index.html) which might be of use.

Also of interest is this page in the Cloud9 documentation which looks at how you can deal with an [XML dump of Wikipedia in MapReduce](http://www.umiacs.umd.edu/~jimmylin/cloud9/docs/content/wikipedia.html).